# Meaning of these verses from a poem by Keats

Tags: meaning, poetry, sentence-meaning

What does these words mean :

> And in the midst of this wide quietness
> A rosy sanctuary will I dress
> With the wreath’d trellis of a working brain,

I'm not a literature student, these verses were written on the first page of psychology textbook.

Comment: The poem is called *Ode to Psyche*.

Comment: The poet says he will build Psyche a temple in a pleasant place in his brain. Psyche had no temples. Keats chooses the brain, as he was a medical student. Today, we might say “mind” or “soul”. https://hekint.org/2019/01/11/reading-the-brain-in-john-keatss-ode-to-psyche/ *And in the midst of this wide quietness* = And in this open and peaceful space / *A rosy sanctuary will I dress* = I will decorate the previously mentioned temple that is filled with roses */ *With the wreath'd trellis of a working brain*, = by using the interwoven framework of my mind.

Comment: It's difficult wording. It's like decoding.